# Discord disconnect and move

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to track disconnect and move users from voice via `fetchAuditLogs` but when admin moves or disconnects a user from the vc, only the first time in 5min is creating in `fetchAuditLogs`, after this, it becomes like admin disconnected 2,3,4... users from voice.

Is there any way to track the changed number or anything that will fix it?

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate',async (voiceOld, voiceNew) => {
  let Fetch_logs = await voiceOld.guild.fetchAuditLogs({ limit: 1, type: "MEMBER_DISCONNECT" })
  console.log(Fetch_logs)
})
```

[image]

track the number if changed or any other ways